# Select all elements of a "class1" until reaching an element with class "should_stop_here is meet"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to select all elements of a "class1" until reaching an element with a class of "should_stop_here"

```html
<li class="class1">A</li>
<li class="class1">B</li>
<li class="class1">C</li>
<li class="class1">D</li>
<li class="should_stop_here">E</li>
<li class="class1">F</li>
<li class="class1">G</li>
<li class="class1">H</li>
```

I've tried using `nextAll('class1')` but I didn't get the results I expected

Comment: You probably need `nextUntil()` in that case, not `nextAll()`, but it depends what element you're calling the function on

Comment: i want to consider all the continuous class here... so the same class if it comes after the different class i dont want it

Comment: ... exactly my point.